# Mode of wickets taken gets two modes

Tags: statistics

[The Data Collected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqhc8.png)

I came across a situation where i got 2 modes, 0 and 1. Now thats probably the answer but 0 wickets dont mean anything anything in the logical sense as 10 players took no wickets while other 10 players did take a wicket. Do i have to apply that kind of logic for this ? Or will the answer remain 0 and 1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, if two different values appear the same number of times in a set of data, then the set has two modes. The set of data is said to be [bimodal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bimodal). If the set of data has more than two modes, it is said to be [multimodal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimodal_distribution).

In your case, the modes are both 0 and 1.

I hope that helps!